# How do I keep my filter list from collapsing?

Tags: javascript, html, css, list, filter

http://testserver.davidbenrimon.com/artists.html

How do I keep the filters in the top right corner visible at all times instead of collapsing?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `custom.js` file, delete this line:

```
$itemsFilter.find('a').not('.active').hide();
```

To remove the mouse events, underneath that line, remove this stuff:

```
// On mouseover (hover)
$itemsFilter.on('mouseenter', function() {
var $this = $(this);

    clearTimeout( mouseOver );

    // Wait 100ms before animating to prevent unnecessary flickering
    mouseOver = setTimeout( function() {
    if( $(window).width() >= 960 )
        $this.find('li a').stop(true, true).slideHorzShow(300);
            }, 100);
        }).on('mouseleave', function() {
            clearTimeout( mouseOver );

    if( $(window).width() >= 960 )
        $(this).find('li a').not('.active').stop(true, true).slideHorzHide(150);
});
```

Comment: Winner winner chicken dinner. I don't know what I'd do without you guys. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I will add this one in the CSS

```
ul#portfolio-items-filter a {
    display: block !important;
}
```

Comment: That partially did the trick! It now shows all of the list items, but it trys to collapse itself and creates an unsightly collapsing effect when moving the cursor around. Hmmm...

Comment: This would work if also overriding various other inline styles that jQuery uses for the animation effect